# Component misses the first update cycle

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue app with a count up component. This component animates the change of a value by counting up from the previous value up to the new one. I forked an offical codesandbox and modified to a small sample

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-mclaren-j13bs
```

I also created a snippet showing the code for the three components

```
https://pastebin.com/ki29jJpm
```

If you open up the codesandbox you can see that the score counter starts at 0. I would expect the code to display a 10 after 5 seconds. After that it should increase to 20 after 5 more seconds and so on...

But the actual result shows that the counter starts with 0 (which is correct), does not update after 5 seconds (which is not correct) and directly counts from 10 to 20 after 5 more seconds (which is correct). The rest of the cycles seem to work fine.

So the first update cycle was not hit. Does someone know how to fix that? After 5 seconds the number should count up from 0 to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see the initial count up to 10 because `<count-up>.update()` is only invoked at `created()` and in a watcher on `<count-up>.initialValue`.

At the start, `initialValue` is 0 and `valueToReach` is 0. After 5 seconds, `initialValue` is 0, and `valueToReach` is 10. Since `initialValue` isn't changed, the watcher is not triggered, and `update()` is not called.

The solution is to add a watcher on `valueToReach` that also calls `update()`:

```js
// CountUp.vue
export default {
  watch: {
    valueToReach() {
      this.update()
    },
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-counter-in-vue-0g0ng?file=/src/components/CountUp.vue)

Comment: I think I don't even need the created hook in the count up component?

Comment: Yeah, I agree `created` isn't needed, since the watchers will kick in anyway.